# Incorrect update in Oracle SQL DB

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to update a lot of rows in date format ('DD-MON-YY'). S

So, in cases such 22-FEB-99, I got 22th February 1999, instead of 22th February 2099.

Is there a way to specify the year in such cases?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but in the meantime: [read about RR in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F). But use 4-digit years if you have a choice; and look at date literals as well. Do you have to deal with dates before 1950? (Your problem description is a bit confusing - I assume you mean you expected 1999, but actually got 2099...)

Comment: @AlexPoole It is possibly the other way round and that the OP has inserted/updated the date column as a string `'22-FEB-99'` and the default format model for implicit string-to-date conversion is `DD-MON-RR` and the `99` has been converted to `1999` rather than the OP's expectation of `2099` and they need to (1) not rely on implicit conversion and (2), if they are going to use a format model, use `YY` rather than `RR` to get the correct year. However, yes, the problem description is confusing and could be clarified with a detailed [MRE].

Comment: Yes, I read it as updating using `to_date(..., 'DD-MON-YY'`)`, but you're probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to update a lot of rows in date format ('DD-MON-YY').

If you have a `DATE` column then that is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes (representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second); it **ALWAYS** has those components and it is **NEVER** stored in any (human-readable) format.

What you probably mean is that your client application (SQL Developer) is **displaying** the dates in the format `DD-MON-RR` and it is not showing you the century or time components.

---

> Is there a way to specify the year in such cases?

Rather than letting the client application apply a default format for displaying the date, you can apply an explicit format using `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'FMDDth Month YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
         AS formatted_date
FROM   your_table;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (your_date_column) AS
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FORMATTED_DATE |
| --- |
| 2nd November 2022 |
| 1st January 2022 |
| 1st January 1970 |

---

> in cases such 22-FEB-99, I got 22th February 1999, instead of 22th February 2099.

If you get the value `22th February 1999` then that is because the date is stored as 1999 and not 2099. Note: that a `DATE` data type always has a century component so the query will display what is stored in the column.

You have probably inserted (or updated) the date as a string:

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table (your_date_column)
VALUES('22-FEB-99');
```

`'22-02-99'` is not a date data type, it is a string literal. Oracle has tried to be helpful and implicitly convert the date to a string using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter effectively converting the query to:

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table (your_date_column)
VALUES(
  TO_DATE(
    '22-FEB-99',
     (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
  )
);
```

However, your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is set to `DD-MON-RR` and the `RR` format model will convert `99` to `1999` and not `2099`.

What you need to do is **NEVER** use implicit conversion from strings to dates; instead:

- Use a date literal:

  ```sql
  INSERT INTO your_table(your_date_column) VALUES (DATE '2099-02-22');
  ```
- Use a timestamp literal (which also allows you to specify the time):

  ```sql
  INSERT INTO your_table(your_date_column) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2099-02-22 00:00:00');
  ```
- Explicitly convert the string using `TO_CHAR` and the correct format model:

  ```sql
  INSERT INTO your_table(your_date_column)
  VALUES (TO_DATE('22-FEB-99', 'DD-MON-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'));
  ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n_V4Zi_-)

---

#### Fixing invalid data

If you have the data as 1999 and want 2099 then you will need to fix it:

```sql
UPDATE your_table
SET    your_date_column = your_date_column + INTERVAL '100' YEAR(3)
WHERE  your_date_column = DATE '1999-02-22';
```

or:

```sql
UPDATE your_table
SET    your_date_column = ADD_MONTHS(your_date_column, 1200)
WHERE  your_date_column = DATE '1999-02-22';
```

or:

```sql
UPDATE your_table
SET    your_date_column = DATE '2099-02-22'
WHERE  your_date_column = DATE '1999-02-22';
```

Answer (score 0):

2-digits year is *evil* (does Y2K ring a bell?). You should really use 4 digits for years. Meanwhile, see whether `YY` vs. `RR` format models do any difference in your case.

(you don't have to alter the session; my database uses different date format and language so I'm setting it now)

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.
```

Sample data and how `yy`/`rr` affect the result:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '22-FEB-99' from dual)
  3  select to_date(col, 'dd-mon-yy') val1,
  4         to_date(col, 'dd-mon-rr') val2
  5  from test;

VAL1       VAL2
---------- ----------
22.02.2099 22.02.1999

SQL>
```